# Display only one post title

Tags: php, wordpress, post, title

The below code displays my selected page, its content and shortcode correctly. The page is selected from a theme options panel in the WP Admin.

I am struggling to echo the post title. At the moment, it's echoing all page titles.

```
<?php
     $blockwho = get_option('good_blockwho');
     $homeblockwho = get_pages ('post_name='.$blockwho); ?>


<?php foreach ($homeblockwho as $hbw) {   
     $content = $hbw->post_content;
     $title = $hbw->post_title;
     apply_filters('the_content', $content);
  
     echo "<h2><span>".$title."</span></h2>";
     echo "".do_shortcode($content)."";
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to echo the title of a singular wordpress page, you do this wordpress function

```
<?php the_title() ?>
```

you can also surround it with some html for css formatting like follows->

```
<h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
```

good luck

Comment: thanks for the response, but im afriad i wasnt looking for the usual wordpress functions, as im not using a the loop. I'm retrieving the page from a select box in the **theme options** i have created so that the homepage can be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

according to the Codex : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

"post_name" is not an argument for get_pages, it's a possible value for "sort_column".

Try the following:

```
<?php
global $post;
$blockwho = get_option('good_blockwho');
$page = get_page_by_title($blockwho);

$myposts = get_posts('post_type=page&p='$page->ID);
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: yea i'd noticed that it wasnt a get pages function also. 
Thanks for your efforts, your code returns all my page titles at the moment, and requires a `.` before `$page->ID`. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     $blockwho = get_option('good_blockwho');
     $homeblockwho = get_pages ('post_name='.$blockwho); ?>


<?php foreach ($homeblockwho as $hbw) {   
     $content = $hbw->post_content;
     $title = $hbw->post_title;
     apply_filters('the_content', $content);

     echo "<h2><span>".$homeblockwho ->post_title."</span></h2>";
     echo "".do_shortcode($content)."";
}?>
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to echo just the one page, this should do the trick:

```
<?php
$blockwho = get_option('good_blockwho');
$page = get_post($blockwho);

$content = $page->post_content;
apply_filters('the_content', $content);

echo "<h2><span>".$page->post_title."</span></h2>";
echo "".do_shortcode($content)."";
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly I would recommend storing the actual page/post ID in the options table rather than the name of it, you can still display page titles to the user, just have a dropdown box with the option values as IDs

Have you checked $page->ID from j-man86's answer is actually returning the correct ID?

Assuming the stored option is a page ID rather than a page title, the following would work

```
$page = get_page(get_option('good_blockwho'));
$title = $page->post_title;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
```